# C++/CLI heap error on delete[]

Tags: c++-cli

I seem to have a problem deleting a `char*` array. It crashes due to heap corruption as `delete[]` gets called:

```
typedef struct _CDB_SYMBOL_INFO {
    char *          name;
    unsigned long   address;
    unsigned long   value;
} CDB_SYMBOL_INFO;

// ...

    for each( Symbol ^ symbol in bls->Symbols )
    {
        CDB_SYMBOL_INFO symbol_info;

        symbol_info.name = new char[symbol->Name->Length];
        Marshal::Copy( symbol->Name->ToCharArray(), 0, IntPtr( (char*) symbol_info.name ), symbol->Name->Length );

        // see enumerate_cdb_symbols_callback(..)
        cdb_call_back(&symbol_info, *call_back);

        delete[] symbol_info.name; // Crashes here
    }

// ...
```

I don't see the problem here ..

---

```
static int enumerate_cdb_symbols_callback(CDB_SYMBOL_INFO * info, void * call_back)
{
    EnumerateSymbolsCallBack *cb = (EnumerateSymbolsCallBack*)call_back;

    Symbol * symbol = alloc_symbol();

    cb(0, symbol);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `cdb_call_back(&symbol_info, *call_back);` actually do? Does it supply a different pointer to `CDB_SYMBOL_INFO` or already frees it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this doesn't do anything at the moment. See my edit. The `CDB_SYMBOL_INFO*` is not touched at all.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on from the code you're currently showing. I can't spot anything obvious. I would check using the debugger 1st if `symbol_info.name`  still carries the same address after that function call and stop using a breakpoint at `delete[] symbol_info.name;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the `Marshal::Copy` overload for an array of 16-bit elements (.NET `System::Char` is not C++ `char`!), and the fourth parameter is the number of elements not the number of bytes, so you're actually copying `symbol->Name->Length * 2` bytes, which is twice the size of your buffer.  The resulting overflow corrupts heap metadata, causing `delete[]` to crash.

Either use a buffer of type `wchar_t`, which is the C++ type that matches `System::Char`, or convert the string to ASCII, perhaps by replacing `ToCharArray()` with `Encoding::ASCII::GetBytes(symbol->Name)`.  Or UTF-8, in which case you can't assume that `symbol->Name->Length` is the necessary buffer size.

An even simpler way is to use the `marshal_as` library that comes with C++/CLI:

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;

for each( Symbol ^ symbol in bls->Symbols )
{
    std::string sym_name = marshal_as<std::string>(symbol->Name);

    CDB_SYMBOL_INFO symbol_info;
    symbol_info.name = &sym_name[0];

    // see enumerate_cdb_symbols_callback(..)
    cdb_call_back(&symbol_info, *call_back);
}
```

It does some unspecified single-byte character encoding (most likely ASCII), and uses RAII to free the memory automatically.

Comment: Muuch better! Thank you. I go with `marshal_as<std::string>(symbol->Name);` as you suggested!